# textureGather() behavior at texel center coordinates

Tags: opengl, glsl

Suppose I have a 100x100 texture and I do the following:

```
vec4 texelQuad = textureGather(sampler, vec2(50.5)/vec2(100.0));
```

The coordinate I am requesting is exactly at the center of texel (50, 50). So, will I get a quad of texels bounded by (49, 49) and (50, 50) or the one bounded by (50, 50) and (51, 51). The spec is evasive on the subject. It merely states the following:

> The rules for the LINEAR minification filter are applied to
>   identify the four selected texels.

The relevant section `8.14.2 Coordinate Wrapping and Texel Selection` of the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) is not terribly clear either. My best hypothesis would be the following:

```
ivec2 lowerBoundTexelCoord = ivec2(floor(textureCoord * textureSize - 0.5));
```

Does that hypothesis hold in practice? No, it doesn't. In fact no other hypothesis would hold either, since different hardware returns different results for this particular case:

```
textureSize:           100x100
textureCoord:          vec2(50.5)/vec2(100.0)
Hyphotesis:            (49, 49) to (50, 50)
GeForce 1050 Ti:       (49, 49) to (50, 50)
Intel HD Graphics 630: (50, 50) to (51, 51)
```

another case:

```
textureSize:           100x100
textureCoord:          vec2(49.5)/vec2(100.0)
Hyphotesis:            (48, 48) to (49, 49)
GeForce 1050 Ti:       (49, 49) to (50, 50)
Intel HD Graphics 630: (48, 48) to (49, 49)
```

Does that make textureGather() useless due to the unpredictable behavior at texel center coordinates? Not at all!. While you may not be able to predict which 4 texels it will return in some particular cases, you can still force it to return the ones you want, by giving it a coordinate between those 4 texels you want. That is, if I want texels bounded by (49, 49) and (50, 50), I would call:

```
textureGather(sampler, vec2(50.0, 50.0)/textureSize);
```

Since the coordinate I am requesting this time is the point where 4 texels meet, any implementation will surely return me those 4 texels.

Now, the question: Is my analysis correct? Does everyone who uses textureGather() force it to return a particular quad of texels rather then figuring out which ones it would return by itself? If so, it's such a shame it's not reflected in any documentation.

**EDIT**

It was pointed out that OpenGL doesn't guarantee the same result dividing identical floating point numbers on different hardware. Therefore, it becomes necessary to mention that in my actual code I had `vec2(50.5)/vec2(textureSize(sampler, 0))` rather than `vec2(50.5)/vec2(100.0)`. That's important, since the presence of `textureSize()` prevents that division from being carried out at shader compilation time.

Let me also rephrase the question:

Suppose you've got a normalized texture coordinate from a black box. That coordinate is then passed to textureGather():

```
vec2 textureCoord = takeFromBlackBox();
vec4 texelQuad = textureGather(sampler, textureCoord);
```

Can anyone produce GLSL code that would return the integer pair of coordinates of the texel returned in texelQuad[3], which is the lower-bound corner of a 2x2 box? The obvious solution below doesn't work in all cases:

```
vec2 textureDims = textureSize(sampler, 0);    
ivec2 lowerBoundTexelCoord = ivec2(floor(textureCoord * textureDims - 0.5));
```

Examples of tricky cases where the above approach may fail are:

```
vec2 textureCoord = vec2(49.5)/vec2(textureSize(sampler, 0)); 
vec2 textureCoord = vec2(50.5)/vec2(textureSize(sampler, 0));
```

where `textureSize(sampler, 0)` returns `ivec2(100, 100)`.

Comment: Rounding error, because `vec2(50.5)/vec2(100.0)` is not exact.

Comment: See: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @DietrichEpp That's beside the point really. You see, I don't care which texels get returned in ambiguous situations, as long as I can predict which those are going to be. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to predict that.

Comment: But that's not a problem with `textureGather`, the problem is that you're passing a different value to `textureGather` on different platforms, and expecting the results to be the same on those different platforms.

Comment: Either use a power-of-two texture, or figure out which texels you're getting with `floor()`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp No, I am passing exactly the same values to textureGather() on different platforms. My hypothesis is evaluated in GLSL as well. And no, you can't figure out the texels you are going to get with floor(), since you different hardware gives you different texels given identical input. More than that, neither the NVidia card nor the Intel integrated one match the behaviour you get from floor().

Comment: How do you know that you're passing the same value on different platforms? Remember that `50.5/100.0` is not guaranteed to give the same result on different platforms.

Comment: Found this rather old discussion: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177090-Custom-Bilinear-filtering-w-textureGather-problem

In author's case, it was "solved" by adding a magic offset of `1/512` to coordinates, but it is implementation specific and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the texel locations for `GL_LINEAR` ([OpenGL 4.6 (Core) §8.14 Texture Minification]) are selected by the following formulas:

> i<sub>0</sub> = wrap(⌊u′ - 1/2⌋)
>
> j<sub>0</sub> = wrap(⌊v′ - 1/2⌋)
>
> ...

The value of (u′,v′) in this case is equal to

```
(vec2(50.5) / vec2(100)) * vec2(100)
```

However, note that this is not guaranteed to be equal to `vec2(50.5)`.  See [The OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 §4.71 Range and Precision](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf):

> a / b, 1.0 / b: 2.5 ULP for b in the range [2<sup>-126</sup>, 2<sup>126</sup>].

So the value of u′ might be slightly larger than 50.5, slightly smaller than 50.5, or it might be 50.5 exactly. No promises! Well, the spec promises no more than 2.5 ULP, but that's nothing to write home about. You can see that when you subtract 0.5 and take the floor, you are either going to get 49 or 50, depending on how the number was rounded.

> i<sub>0</sub> = wrap(⌊(50.5 / 100) * 100 - 1/2⌋)
>
> i<sub>0</sub> = wrap(⌊(.505 ± error) * 100 - 1/2⌋)
>
> i<sub>0</sub> = wrap(⌊50.5 ± error - 1/2⌋)
>
> i<sub>0</sub> = wrap(⌊50 ± error⌋)
>
> i<sub>0</sub> = 50 (if error >= 0) or 49 (if error < 0)

So in fact it is not `textureGather()` that is behaving unpredictably. The unpredictable part is the rounding error when you try to divide by 100, which is explained in the GLSL spec and in the classic article,  [WhatEvery Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Or in other words, `textureGather()` always gives you the same result, but `50.5/100.0` does not.

Note that you could get exact results if your texture were a power of two, since you could use `50.5 * 0.0078125` to compute `50.5 / 128`, and the result would be exactly correct, since multiplication is correctly rounded and 0.0078125 is a power of two.

Comment: OK, I didn't know OpenGL doesn't guarantee you to get the same result dividing the same numbers on different hardware. However, that's still beside the point. Suppose you've got a normalized texture coordinate from a black box. That division of `vec2(50.5)/vec2(100.0)` is just such a black box. In fact, in my actual code it's `vec2(50.5)/vec2(textureSize(...))`, which is suddenly an important difference. Now, you pass that coordinate from a black box to textureGather(). Can you produce a piece of code that will accurately predict the texels that are going to be returned? I wasn't able to.

Comment: @Tulon: You can accurately predict the texels that will be gathered, as long as you can accurately predict the value you are passing to `textureGather()`. **THIS HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH `textureGather()`**

Comment: @Tulon: Why do you need to predict things exactly anyway? If your code is relying on floating-point division giving you an exact result, we can help you fix the code so it is less sensitive to the way actual floating-point numbers work on real hardware. However, `textureGather()` is not at fault here.

Comment: I want the predictor to give an accurate prediction for any normalized texture coordinate, even those exactly at or very close to a texel center. Obviously I didn't have any `(x + 0.5)/100.0` in the production code I had problems with. Those I came up with for the reproducer. As for why I need textureGather() in the first place, well I use those 4 texels to calculate both the interpolated value and the gradient at a given point. My texture is actually a single channel signed distance map. Neither of those you can implement without predicting which 4 texels will be returned.

Comment: Well, actually you can implement those without a predictor using the workaround I proposed in my question. However, the workaround essentially implements an integer-coordinate version of textureGather() in terms of the normal textureGather(). I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: How are you reading back the values of `lowerBoundTexelCoord`?

Comment: You mean in my workaround? I simply use the predictor I proposed in my question, except now it doesn't predict which texels are returned by textureGather(), but rather it tells textureGather() which texels it should fetch.

Comment: How do you know that it's not giving you the correct results?

Comment: You mean how do I know my predictor failed to predict what textureGather() is going to return? Well, for the reproducer I created an integer texture and initialized it like this: `texture_data[y * width + x] = y * 10000 + x;`. I then write the texels returned by textureGather() to SSBO and print them on the host side. I get output like `490048 490049 480049 480048` which shows both coordinates. I do the same with my predicted coordinates.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if this can be avoided by using the `precise` qualifier.

Comment: Tried it with `precise` on both Intel and NVidia GPUs, but no, it doesn't help on either.