# Can an OpenGL shader do a mix of nearest and linear scaling?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm porting some old OpenGL 1.2 bitmap font rendering code to modern OpenGL (at least OpenGL 3.2+), and I'm wondering if I can use a GLSL shader to achieve what I've been doing manually.

When I want to draw the string "123", scaled to particular size, I do the following steps with the sprites below.

[image]

1. I draw the sprite to the screen, scaled 2x with GL_NEAREST. However, to get a black outline, I actually draw the sprite several times.

   1. x + 1, y + 0, BLACK
   2. x + 0, y + 1, BLACK
   3. x - 1, y + 0, BLACK
   4. x + 0, y - 1, BLACK
   5. x + 0, y + 0, COLOR (RED)

   [image]
2. After the sprites have been drawn to the screen, I copy the screen to a texture, via glCopyTexSubImage2D.
3. I draw that texture back to the screen, but with GL_LINEAR.

The end result is a more visually appealing form of scaling pixel sprites. When upscaling small pixel sprites to arbitrary dimensions, using just GL_NEAREST (bottom-right) or just GL_LINEAR (bottom-left) gives an effect I don't like. Pixel doubling with GL_NEAREST, and then do the remaining scaling with GL_LINEAR, gives a result that I prefer (top).

[image]

I'm pretty sure GLSL can do the black outline (thus saving me from having to do lots of draws), but could it also do the combination of GL_NEAREST and GL_LINEAR scaling?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the effect of "2x nearest-neighbour upscaling followed by linear sampling" by pretending to sample a 4-texel neighbourhood from the upscaled texture while in reality sampling them from the original one. Then you'll have to implement bilinear interpolation manually. If you were targeting OpenGL 4+, `textureGather()` would be useful, though do keep [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413746/texturegather-behavior-at-texel-center-coordinates) in mind. In my proposed solution below, I'll be using 4 `texelFetch()` calls, rather than `textureGather()`, as `textureGather()` would complicate things quite a bit.

Suppose you have an unscaled texture with black borders around the glyphs already present. Let's assume you have a normalized texture coordinate of `vec2 pn = ...` into that texture, where `pn.x` and `pn.y` are between 0 and 1. The following code should achieve the desired effect, though I haven't tested it:

```
ivec2 origTexSize = textureSize(sampler, 0);
int upscaleFactor = 2;

// Floating point texel coordinate into the upscaled texture.
vec2 ptu = pn * vec2(origTexSize * upscaleFactor);

// Decompose "ptu - 0.5" into the integer and fractional parts.
vec2 ptuf;
vec2 ptui = modf(ptu - 0.5, ptuf);

// Integer texel coordinates into the upscaled texture.
ivec2 ptu00 = ivec2(ptui);
ivec2 ptu01 = ptu00 + ivec2(0, 1);
ivec2 ptu10 = ptu00 + ivec2(1, 0);
ivec2 ptu11 = ptu00 + ivec2(1, 1);

// Integer texel coordinates into the original texture.
ivec2 pt00 = clamp(ptu00 / upscaleFactor, ivec2(0), origTexSize - 1);
ivec2 pt01 = clamp(ptu01 / upscaleFactor, ivec2(0), origTexSize - 1);
ivec2 pt10 = clamp(ptu10 / upscaleFactor, ivec2(0), origTexSize - 1);
ivec2 pt11 = clamp(ptu11 / upscaleFactor, ivec2(0), origTexSize - 1);

// Sampled colours.
vec4 clr00 = texelFetch(sampler, pt00, 0);
vec4 clr01 = texelFetch(sampler, pt01, 0);
vec4 clr10 = texelFetch(sampler, pt10, 0);
vec4 clr11 = texelFetch(sampler, pt11, 0);

// Bilinear interpolation.
vec4 clr0x = mix(clr00, clr01, ptuf.y);
vec4 clr1x = mix(clr10, clr11, ptuf.y);
vec4 clrFinal = mix(clr0x, clr1x, ptuf.x);
```